# Adding corresponding JS file to a new Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js and it's been really awesome so far but I ran into a problem trying to add another JS file. I have a Navigation.vue file and I'm trying to add a new Vue instance to corrsponde with it, but I'm not having any success.

#### Navigation.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#navigation',
  data: {
    active: 'home'
  },
  methods: {
    makeActive: function(item) {
      this.active = item;
    }
  }
});
```

#### Navigation.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="navigation">
    <nav v-bind:class="active" v-on:click.prevent>
        <a href="#" class="home" v-on:click="makeActive('home')">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="projects" v-on:click="makeActive('projects')">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" class="services" v-on:click="makeActive('services')">Services</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact" v-on:click="makeActive('contact')">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  }
</script>
```

#### Application.js

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm"
import App from '../app.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  const app = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {
      App
    }
  })

  console.log(app)
})
```

The Navigation.js file isn't working. I think it's because I haven't imported it right, but I'm not sure?

#### ERROR:

```
Property or method "active" is not defined on the instance but 
referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, 
either in the data option, or for class-based components, by 
initializing the property
```

Comment: You don't typically create a new `Vue` instance for components. I'd expect to see your `Navigation` component included in your `App` component

Comment: It is but how do I add Javascript code for the navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd expect to see is your `Navigation` component included in your `App` component.

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navigation/>
    <!-- there's probably more than just this -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from 'path/to/Navigation.vue'

export default {
  // snip
  components: {
    Navigation
  }
  // snip
}
</script>
```

Also, component data should be a function

> Navigation.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return { active: 'home' }
  },
  methods: {
    makeActive (item) {
      this.active = item;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

There's no need to include `Navigation.js` or have a separate `Vue` instance for your `Navigation` component